# How to say "Your eyes whispered:'Have we met?' "in Chinese?

Tags: translation, lyrics

It's from Taylor's song*Enchanted*.I need an answer as close to it as possible.

Answer (score 1):

A quick *baiduing* revealed:

[Wenku (Baidu)](http://wenku.baidu.com/link?url=1Z7GIWhVnKswwcjFImS50XJU3FVuTJg9j9N4Ocw4Z2XELGsTRRNrgpyQOuUKx4s7NRWyVG-kVgjfDuvCqzYKwsQI3NRy0zA6mugCdIZXZoq):

> Your eyes whispered "Have we met?" 你的眼低于呢喃，我们是否曾经遇

[Zhidao (Baidu)](http://zhidao.baidu.com/link?url=m5MmatL_sKxHmcxMH1HBnk6NcAIVM8L4vXOIjbaE_W0TLBon5puITTLh01D2yKLUxOBeqe4N0oMoUBjHoWgw2a):

> Your eye's whispered "have we met?" 你的眼睛悄悄向我传达着“我们以前见过吗”

[Tieba (Baidu)](http://tieba.baidu.com/p/1382754971)

> 你迷人双眼像是在低语“我们曾否见过面？”
>
> Your eyes whispered "have we met?"

[Music (Baidu)](http://music.baidu.com/search/lrc?key=%E9%AD%94%E6%B3%95%E5%A5%87%E7%BC%98)

> Your eyes whispered "have we met?" / 你眼低语：“我们见过？”

...lot's of translations online, take your pick...

Comment: 文库知道贴吧音乐OTZ哈哈原来是同胞~来握个爪~网上翻译好多，感觉都达不到信达雅，眼睛低语还凑活吧..

Comment: 信达雅? wat iz dat?